# How to change background from static jpg to animated gif picture, but only after script done

Tags: javascript, html, css

Theres full html code.
Hope somebody help me with it. Please.
Need to change background image to another one, but only when Curves script be doned.
Trying to find answer by google, but cant.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <html>
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <style>
          body {
           background: #141414 url(Wallpaper.jpg);
           }
         </style>
        </head>
        <body>
         <p>...</p>
        </body>
       </html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>HTML5 Canvas</title>

<script src="Modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

Theres some script things

<title>HTML5 Canvas Generative Art</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body {background-color:#141414; overflow: hidden;}
        #caption {position:absolute; width:1360px; text-align:center; top:688px; z-index:1}
    canvas {}
        #displayCanvas {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:0;}
    div {}
        #container {width:1360px; height:688px; margin:auto;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> 
    <canvas id="displayCanvas" width="1360px" height="688">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.
    </canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

full html code in Drive Google:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkcyJT8pqgMd3IJXSrdqH4F7lRZ91eV8/view)

Comment: What "Curves script"?

Comment: its a Modernizr MorphingCurves script from modernizr.com

Comment: need to load the *.jpg image first, then the "Modernizer MorphingCurves2" script happened on its background and only after that the background is replaced with a *.gif image, but so that the lines drawn by the Modernizer remain on top of the recently loaded *.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code at the bottom of your document. And any external js files you're loading, put them above the below script tag. That should work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // window.onload will ensure the document is fully loaded before running the below script
  window.onload = (event) => {
    // Your other scripts you'd like to execute before changing the background

    // Code to change background
    document.body.style.background = "url('new_image.gif')";
  };
</script>
```

Update:

Your mark up is not properly created. Keeping the tags consistent and putting the relevant tags within head and body is a good practice. Refer to the code below.

```js
// window.onload will ensure the document is fully loaded before running the below script
window.onload = (event) => {
  // Your other scripts you'd like to execute before changing the background

  // Code to change background
  document.body.style.background = "url('https://i.imgur.com/cCqp22b.gif')";
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #141414 url(Wallpaper.jpg);
}

body {
  background - color: #141414;
  overflow: hidden;
}

# caption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1360 px;
  text - align: center;
  top: 688 px;
  z - index: 1
}

canvas {}

# displayCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 px;
  left: 0 px;
  z - index: 0;
}

div {}

# container {
  width: 1360 px;
  height: 688 px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Canvas</title>
    <script src="Modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>...</p>
    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="displayCanvas" width="1360px" height="688">Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas. 
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I embed "window.onload" into the script itself, no errors appear in vscode, but it does not work and the picture does not change after the script is executed, and if I enter outside the script, then vscode gives multiple errors and nothing works at all

Comment: but I like your version more, it seems to me that it suits me, I just incorrectly embed it in the code

Comment: ther is my html file, can you look it please [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkcyJT8pqgMd3IJXSrdqH4F7lRZ91eV8/view)

Comment: Requested access

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkcyJT8pqgMd3IJXSrdqH4F7lRZ91eV8/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `style.background` property using JavaScript after the script is loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body {
  background: url("paper.gif");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--Load some script here-->
<script>
setTimeout(()=>document.body.style.background = "url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f4/52/a2/f452a2f4b634b3011e065da8eaf0a5c3.gif')",1500);//simulate waiting
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but then the delay will be equal to the value of the "setTimeout" parameter in the example set to 1500, and under different circumstances, the speed of drawing lines by the script may vary. Maybe there is a way to replace the background just after the script draws the lines

Comment: maybe there is a parameter like "when the script = finished" or some..

Comment: @РомаКОбромовеч There's no need to set the delay at all as long as your script is after the other script.

Comment: The delay was only set to simulate waiting. In your actual code, you don't need `setTimeout`.